# Pycharm Notebook - Remote jupyter server can't access source root

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

#### Steps to reproduce in **PyCharm IDE**

```
- Create a jupyter server remotely.
- Add that server as a remote server
- Configure remote python kernel and setup remote deployment
- Create a folder with a file you want to import into your notebook
- Add that folder as a source folder
- Import a module from the source folder
```

#### Expected Result

The files in the source folder can be imported

#### Actual Result

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxx'

Comment: Did you say `import module` or did you say `import folder.module`?

Comment: I tried both, the problem is I think because of remote deployment. The source rooting step adds the local directory to the source. However, while running the notebook it runs on the server and can't access the local source root. I wanted to see if there was a workaround.